# Data split using model's error

Tags: model, error, stratification, train-test-split

For splitting of the data into train/test/val I use stratified sampling. Then I confirm that metadata distributions represent the original dataset well enough.

I want to start considering error of the existing model as another variable. The model was trained on different dataset. I think that having the error distributed identically across all 3 parts will help to balance the bias/variance tradeoff better. My worry is the potential data leakage.

But I wasn't able to find any counter-argument. Can you help me to sort this out?

Comment: This seems circular. You want to build a model using a train/test/val split. But you want to choose the split on the basis of the model's predictions in each of those partitions.

Comment: I think we can assume I already have an existing model trained on different dataset. Or I could lay-out a temporary model just for the purpose of the split. I've edited the original question - thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I think if you read up on how bias and variance of a model are measured, you'll find that this proposal is not statistically meaningful. One place to start is *Elements of Statistical Learning*.

Comment: My reasoning was that having the error distributed identically both in train and test set will a) help model to generalize better and b) me to measure the convergence using the test set. Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you construct a proof that you’re correct?

Comment: @Sycorax - Taking one step back - I've read parts of the _Elements of Statistical Learning_.  Did you mean by *proposal not being statistically meaningful* that in the average case outcomes will be the same? I mean, If I tried a large number of random splits and compared them to the large number of splits considering the error the average performance of the trained model would be the same. I'm trying to understand if my proposal would lead to better results faster - e.g. what if I had just a single data split? Was this your point?

Comment: @Sycorax - regarding the proof. I would operate with assumption of having difficult data points present in the dataset. My goal would be to have them equally present in the train and test sets. The proxy model's error gives me information about the "difficulty" (bias or variance). Therefore I can prefer splits with similar distributions of "difficulty" between train and test. In the average case this will lead to the same results, but in practice search for the ideal splits will be easier, right?

Comment: "The *generalization* performance of a learning method relates to its prediction capability on independent test data." *ESL*, page 219. You've described a procedure to systematically ensure that there is no independent test data, therefore you're not measuring *generalization.* The usual way to hedge against an "unlucky" split is to repeat the train/test split (or repeat cross-validation).

Comment: Thank you! I know that test set is meant to be independent. But I thought I was extending the _Stratified sampling_ method described in _A stratified traffic sampling methodology for seeing the big picture_. This method involves detection of clusters and randomly splitting these data subsets. Does this method of sampling break the independence rule? Is it fair to even look into the structure of the data? My idea was to define these clusters based on error and perform the random splitting.

Comment: A stratification split is done in such a way that the probability of two samples being included in the same partition is independent conditional on the stratifying variable. In your scenario, the split is not because (1) not random, because you're optimizing the splitting criterion and (2) depends on the model which has already seen all of the data. In other words, it's not an independent set because choosing the split depends on the model that's scored the test data.

Comment: Thank you for you time! I'm still missing the last piece of the puzzle. Even though the strata are defined using the scoring model the two-sample independence should be secured using the random sampling from subgroups, doesn't it? In other words - if someone defined strata with evil intentions shouldn't the randomization protect the independence?

Comment: That seems like a different question.

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding. Maybe I should reformulate my question. I would like to use model's error to define strata and then randomly sample from each stratum. Correct me if I'm wrong but that should be the stratified way of how to ensure that both train / test contain the same distribution of error. Do you find this approach acceptable?